# How do I find out what version of DB2 LUW introduced support for NVARCHAR?

Tags: unicode, nvarchar, db2-luw

I'm having a very hard time googling for what should be straightforward answer: at what version did DB2 LUW introduce support for the NVARCHAR data type (and other national-language types, of course).

I know from experience within my own organisation that they are supported at 9.7.300.3885, but are not at 9.7.0.441. That suggests that they came at a point release of 9.7, which is surprising, but not as surprising as nothing apparently announcing the fact.

I'd like to know so that we can tell our clients the minimum version we can support, but I'd also like to know *how* to find out, both for my own interest and because it should make a more useful SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically listed in the *What's New* section of the manual: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0054110.html?lang=en

Comment: Thanks, @mustaccio. It says "Starting with Version 9.7 Fix Pack 2, national character support has been extended by means of the NCHAR, NVARCHAR, and NCLOB spelling for the graphic data types," so I'm guessing that would translate to 9.7.2.x? I'd still be interested in knowing how you found your way to that specific page.

Comment: Expand the _What's New_ section in the online knowledge center, or search for "NVARCHAR".